# Web Services or Custom Protocol?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

I have no experience with web services. Historically I've built client-server systems using proprietary communication protocols (even they happen to be XML). I just spent a few hours looking over Axis2 and it sent a shudder down my spine. The learning curve of WS scares me, and seeing all that XML surround so little functionality makes me wonder if it's worth the trouble.

How do you decide whether you need to use Web Services or a custom communication protocol? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach and what use-cases are they best suited for?

**Please post a clear guideline, not an opinion piece :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build RESTful web APIs; then you get a lot of automatic caching and etc benefits that you don't get if you use other methods (SOAP, XML-RPC, etc)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106546/performance-of-soap-vs-xml-rpc-or-rest#106701) for more details

Another benefit is that if you build a RESTful API for your code to use, you can potentially let your users take advantage of it too - they often have uses for your product that you never dreamed of.

Comment: What do you think of Axis2 then? http://ws.apache.org/axis2/ claims to support REST-style invocations for Web Services.

Comment: Never used it, so no opinion, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"Web Services" as defined by the W3C means using SOAP over HTTP.  SOAP is severe overkill in most cases; it's only really appropriate (IMO) when you're making a public service available to the world, like an API for interacting with your website, for example.

Anything else (especially internal, private communications) rarely need anything more complex than XML-RPC.  Only if performance is an issue should you consider a more condensed protocol; XML-RPC is so simple and widely-supported that the ease of development and debugging more than makes up for the performance loss of using bloaty ol' XML.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there are a number of frameworks out there that make programming web services very trivial stuff. In the VB / C# world .Net makes it a joy. I'm not really sure about specific frameworks for other languages but I am sure most have at least one.

The standardisation and simplicity of implementation and reuse of web services make them very attractive. As previously pointed out- yes, they make communications very verbose. If you are worried about this why not calculate how much data you actually will be trasmitting. chances are, with current network and internet speeds, it will be trivial - even with the XML overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I would always use the custom data formats as a last resort and not a first. What widely used method you use it up to you but it's unlikely you would go wrong with Web Services model.

Maintainability and extensibility are the main benefits. The use of widely used technology your solution will be easier for someone else to understand plus you can use ready to roll libraries as [consumers](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) and [providers](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently broken my custom protocol habit. I am now using Apache on the server side and libCurl plus libxml2 to load and parse the XML on the client which is written in C++.

The server side can be either PHP or a CGI written in a more serious language. Depends what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Webservices have the advantage of being somewhat standard, so it's possible for programs you've never heard of to use a webservice you wrote.  Using HTTP can help them communicate over proxies and other network obstacles without any extra work from you.  The XML, although rather verbose and ugly, is rather easier to read when debugging than binary data.

When you're transferring stuff over the network, it's unlikely that serialisation/deserialisation to xml will be the limiting factor in performance.  It can be a bit of hassle, although a library to do it for you will help a lot.

Comment: Right, but what's the difference between Web Services and a documented custom protocol that also happens to use HTTP and XML?

Answer (score 0):

In my personal (old cranky dude) opinion, web services should only be used as a way to make some of your internal information available to third parties (i.e. other companies, people outside your organization etc.).  Of course, that is *also* the originally intended purpose of XML. :-)

If you have access to a direct connection with the databases containing the information your application needs - that is the way to go.  It's faster and simpler - which in application development means "better" and "less buggy".

Answer (score 0):

SOAP and XML -- "all that XML surround so little functionality makes me wonder if it's worth the trouble."

Totally.  SOAP is heavy-weight, and -- to a large extent -- a workaround to the need for static binding throughout the Java technology stack.

REST, on the other hand, is much lighter weight.  Further, REST with JSON or REST with YAML is very lightweight, and very easy to implement.  It builds right on top of the off-the shelf HTTP protocol.

REST requires you to define resources (named via URI's), and transactions based on the canonical CRUD rules (GET, POST, PUT and DELETE).  Very simple and canonical.