# SOAP vs RESTful performance issue on lower bandwith (2G Service)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

We have a android based application that gets data from the server using web services. Currently for consuming web services we are using SOAP protocol.
But for production roll out we are using 2G network and 2G has lower bandwidth. Because of this performance of the application is not good during syncing of the data from the server.
We are thinking that we should use REST design instead of SOAP and that will increase our performance for consuming web services. Is it right?

Kindly guide us in this issue. And our major concern is network connectivity with less data bandwidth for consuming web services.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163066/rest-vs-soap-has-rest-a-better-performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In performance REST is comparatively better than SOAP. Even Google advices android developers to use REST. (Dont have exact link right now).

> While SOAP services always return XML, REST services provide
>   flexibility in regards to the type of data returned. A REST endpoint
>   can just as easily return a payload of XML data as a PNG image. The de
>   facto standard for data payloads from REST services is JSON.  This is
>   because of the AJAX heritage of REST wherein JavaScript easily
>   consumes JSON data. Initially Android and iOS did not contain JSON
>   parsing frameworks as part of the OS, but in later revisions that
>   functionality has been added. JSON payloads are usually smaller than
>   their XML counterparts; if SOAP envelope overhead is included
>   REST+JSON payloads are dramatically smaller.

Source : http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/jack-cox/soap-vs-rest-mobile-services
This might help : http://javatheelixir.blogspot.com/2009/12/soap-vs-rest-in-service-layer-for.html