# Unexplained performance difference between WCF rest vs SOAP webservice

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap, wcf-rest

We are exploring whether it is worth it to switch from SOAP webservices to REST. I have created a REST webservice with the following info:

```
 [ServiceContract]
 public interface IRestServiceImpl
 {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "Execute")]
    ExecuteResponse Execute(ExecuteRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "ExecutePutJSON")]
    ExecuteResponse ExecutePutJSON(ExecuteRequest request);
}
```

The implementation code behind (RestServiceImpl.svc.cs) is as follows:

```
public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
{
    public ExecuteResponse Execute(ExecuteRequest request)
    {
       //processing code that returns ExecuteResponse
    }

    public ExecuteResponse Execute(ExecuteRequest request)
    {
       //processing code that returns ExecuteResponse
    }
}
```

The RestServiceImpl.svc is as follows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CICJIS.IWS.RestServiceImpl" 
CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs" %>
```

The Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
      switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages" />
        </listeners>
    </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
 </sources>
 <sharedListeners>
  <add name="messages"
     type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="C:\Logs\RestService.svclog" />
 </sharedListeners>
 <trace autoflush="true" />
 </system.diagnostics>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="999999" maxQueryStringLength="999999"
    executionTimeout="999"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
   <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
        logEntireMessage="true"
        logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
        maxMessagesToLog="3000"
        maxSizeOfMessageToLog="10000000" />
    </diagnostics>

   <services>
      <service name="RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IRestServiceImpl" 
          behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

The implementation code behind does the same thing as the SOAP webservice and returns the same ExecuteResponse Object.
I consumed the two services through fiddler to obtain the statistics on how long it took to get a response back.
The SOAP webservice uses ws-security but the REST webservice does not have any security implemented.
What I found was that the SOAP webservice returns the response much faster than the REST webservice.

I'm not sure if maybe the scenario we have is not well suited for a REST service or maybe I've implemented the REST webservice incorrectly?
I've also tried debugging both the REST and SOAP service and found that when it breaks in the method, the processing code in both methods completes at the same rate, but it takes longer for the response to return to the REST client than the SOAP client. Is it possible that the WCF api for REST is slower than the WCF api for SOAP when serializing the objects?

The following is an example of the stats from fiddler :

For SOAP:
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      13,693 (headers:299; body:13,394)
Bytes Received:  2,651,288 (headers:235; body:2,651,053)
ClientConnected: 16:12:39.775
ClientBeginRequest: 16:12:39.775
GotRequestHeaders: 16:12:39.775
ClientDoneRequest: 16:12:40.120
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup: 0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 1ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 16:12:40.122
FiddlerBeginRequest: 16:12:40.122
ServerGotRequest: 16:12:40.122
ServerBeginResponse: 16:12:40.123
GotResponseHeaders: 16:13:25.744
ServerDoneResponse: 16:13:26.863
ClientBeginResponse: 16:13:25.744
ClientDoneResponse: 16:13:26.863
Overall Elapsed: 00:00:47.0877083
application/soap+xml: 2,651,053
~headers~: 235

For REST:
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      2,369 (headers:298; body:2,071)
Bytes Received:  1,982,735 (headers:230; body:1,982,505)
ClientConnected: 16:12:07.728
ClientBeginRequest: 16:12:32.427
GotRequestHeaders: 16:12:32.427
ClientDoneRequest: 16:12:32.428
Determine Gateway: 0ms
DNS Lookup: 0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 2ms
HTTPS Handshake: 0ms
ServerConnected: 16:12:32.430
FiddlerBeginRequest: 16:12:32.430
ServerGotRequest: 16:12:32.431
ServerBeginResponse: 16:12:32.435
GotResponseHeaders: 16:20:06.914
ServerDoneResponse: 16:20:07.889
ClientBeginResponse: 16:20:06.914
ClientDoneResponse: 16:20:07.889
Overall Elapsed:
00:07:35.4626091
application/xml: 1,982,505
      ~headers~: 230

The big difference between the two services is at ServerBeginResponse to GotResponseHeaders.
I've repeated this test several times and got similar findings.

Anyone experience the same finding?

Comment: I posted this same question in a Microsoft forum and got great responses. The following is the link to the Microsoft discussions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a4b10fac-cc7d-48d6-81ee-b798b2062927/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163066/rest-vs-soap-has-rest-a-better-performance

Comment: It looks like ASP.net web api is better for REST webservices. The performance degradation is within the WCF framework for REST. WCF is great for SOAP but not REST. After doing the same test with REST on ASP.net web API, I noticed that it performs much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on the framework being used to implement REST services.
I had recently worked on JAXWS RI(Metro) based application and later ported it into a JAX RS (Jersey) framework.
I could get better response times per service call for the Rest based implementation

Comment: This is what I found as well. Looks like ASP.net web api is better for REST than WCF.