# WCF SOAP vs WCF REST performance

Tags: c#, .net, rest, soap, soa

We are trying to create a solution for high frequency trading application on SOA. As resident of .NET, we are using WCF services. Searching Google, I found REST payload is less than the SOAP payload. REST is faster than the SOAP. At the same time, SOAP has some other advantages like Transaction support, more binding support, so on.

1. Which will be faster netTCPbinding with SOAP or REST with JSON?
2. Which one should has more advantages for high load and low latency system?

Any pointers?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but in a broader sense I would say that SOAP is "so last decade (and beyond)" and REST is definitely the current standard.

Comment: @user2269520 There is a Msdn Blog article about REST WCF vs. WebAPI performance test. It seems that there are some situations that one of them performs faster.[basic links](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fkaduk/2014/01/07/rest-wcf-vs-webapi-throughput-performance/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking REST has a better performance, you may check this entry [Rest vs. Soap. Has REST a better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163066/rest-vs-soap-has-rest-a-better-performance)

Anyway for HFT this could be not enough, as Udi said, you may pay attention to your application architecture and your infrastructure, avoid closing connections, use TCP protocol directly instead HTTP, use non-blocking io technics to improve TPS, maybe using messaging systems (kind of JMS) ...

is a broad topic

Answer (score 0):

For any type of low latency scenario, you should be avoiding network calls like the plague. If you really want to play in the HFT space, you'll need to handle much deeper architectural questions than the ones raised here.