# How to customize an xml request using XmlRpc-Client

Tags: xmlrpcclient

I've got this issue: I'm trying to send a custom xml request using the XmlRpc-Client from Apache. I got an instance of XmlRpcClient and it contains some methods called "execute " and look like this:

```
public class RPCClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
            config.setServerURL(new URL("http://localhost:8888/SOAP"));

            XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
            client.setConfig(config);

            Object[] params = new Object[]{new Integer(4), new Integer(3)};
            String myResponse = (String) client.execute("A_Method", params);

            System.out.println("Suc " + myResponse);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Err " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And it is sending this:

```
POST /SOAP HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: Apache XML RPC 3.1.3 (Sun HTTP Transport)
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: ***********
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 200

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <methodCall>
      <methodName>A_Method</methodName>
      <params>
         <param>
            <value>
               <i4>4</i4>
            </value>
         </param>
         <param>
            <value>3</value>
         </param>
      </params>
   </methodCall>
```

In short, this client have no an "execute" method to receive a simple string, or something alike. So my question is how can I send my custom xml, that should look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:rp="http://www.abcdef.com/GH"xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">   
   <soapenv:Header>   </soapenv:Header>   
   <soapenv:Body>      
      <rp:A_Methodsoapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">         
         <package xsi:type="xsd:string">string1</package>         
         <event xsi:type="xsd:string">string2</event>         
         <fields xsi:type="rp:ArrayOfKeyValuePair" soapenc:arrayType="rp:KeyValuePair[]">        
            <item xsi:type="rp:KeyValuePair">                       
               <key xsi:type="xsd:string">string3</key>                         
               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">123</value>        
            </item>        
         </fields>      
      </rp:A_Method>   
   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache XML-RPC](https://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/index.html) is for communication with the [XML-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) protocol. The message you are trying to send is [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), a different protocol (see the question ["What's the difference between XML-RPC and SOAP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80112/whats-the-difference-between-xml-rpc-and-soap)).

To send this message you can either send it as plain text (if it's only one simple message) using a regular HTTP client, or use a full blown SOAP library.

Comment: I know this is a fairly old question, but it was the top ranked question here for "XmlRpcClient".